# Pagerfanta reverse order pagination

Tags: symfony, pagerfanta

My question is : is it possible to easily make WhiteOctoberPagerFantaBundle for SF2 in reverse order?

I mean, when we normally have pagination: 1, 2, 3 (newest content at the 1 page) -> to make : 241,240,239,.... ( newest content at the 241).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. I just take a look in the PagerFanta source code, and the page position is hard coded.

```
private function generatePages()
{
    $this->calculateStartAndEndPage();

    return $this->previous().
           $this->first().
           $this->secondIfStartIs3().
           $this->dotsIfStartIsOver3().
           $this->pages().
           $this->dotsIfEndIsUnder3ToLast().
           $this->secondToLastIfEndIs3ToLast().
           $this->last().
           $this->next();
}
```

Maybe by editing this portion of code to store elements as an array before "imploding" them, and add a `reverse` option which, if is true, will make an `array_reverse` on the result...

Comment: I will check that, thank you. Give an answer if succeed.